# Facing error "Your latest production release contains SDK issues - ADS sdk"?

Tags: android, google-play, ads, google-ads-api

​The error coming is

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:17.1.1
This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Upgrade to a newer version (19.3.0+).
Starting from August 2, 2023 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release new versions which contain this SDK version.
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1
This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Upgrade to a newer version (19.4.0+).
This SDK version has a note from the SDK developer. Here's what the SDK developer told us:
This version is officially deprecated, and will soon disable ad loading. Please update to a new version. See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/deprecation for more details.
Starting from August 2, 2023 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release new versions which contain this SDK version.
```

**
But the thing is in my project I have not used any of this sdks.**

Depencies file -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/16gvG0c8BDw1TXdfS-IWvTx12daEtgmO0/view?usp=drive_link

This is the file, but i am unable to understand from this.

Comment: You are, but you just don't know. Your dependencies also rely on dependencies. And those dependency might be using an outdated version than what's supported.